# Spark property that kills the spark application after a certain number of failed executors

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes

I have a spark application running with a driver and two executors. These executors have been failing and new ones are being created endlessly. **I'm looking for a way to tell the spark operator (through a spark property maybe?) to stop trying and to permanently fail the spark application after a few executors are lost.**

At first I thought `"spark.task.maxFailures": "2"` would help me but it doesn't actually fail the application.

We were first using Spark version `2.4.4` and the spark application didn't use to keep trying to spawn new executors indefinitely like this. We upgraded Spark to version `3.0.1` and only now we see this behavior.

Update - adding logs of the how the pods are failing and being recreated.
kubectl get logs

```
NAME                                           READY   STATUS      RESTARTS   AGE
bats-4ec00395a68a46939381e78e5545198b-driver   0/1     Completed   0          7h51m
bats-4ec00395a68a46939381e78e5545198b-driver   0/1     Terminating   0          8h
bats-4ec00395a68a46939381e78e5545198b-driver   0/1     Terminating   0          8h
bats-4ec00395a68a46939381e78e5545198b-driver   0/1     Pending       0          0s
bats-4ec00395a68a46939381e78e5545198b-driver   0/1     Pending       0          0s
bats-4ec00395a68a46939381e78e5545198b-driver   0/1     ContainerCreating   0          0s
bats-4ec00395a68a46939381e78e5545198b-driver   1/1     Running             0          4s
4ec00395a68a46939381e78e5545198b-bba8d875fb41e88d-exec-1   0/1     Pending             0          1s
4ec00395a68a46939381e78e5545198b-bba8d875fb41e88d-exec-1   0/1     Pending             0          1s
4ec00395a68a46939381e78e5545198b-bba8d875fb41e88d-exec-2   0/1     Pending             0          0s
4ec00395a68a46939381e78e5545198b-bba8d875fb41e88d-exec-2   0/1     Pending             0          0s
4ec00395a68a46939381e78e5545198b-bba8d875fb41e88d-exec-1   0/1     ContainerCreating   0          1s
4ec00395a68a46939381e78e5545198b-bba8d875fb41e88d-exec-2   0/1     ContainerCreating   0          0s
4ec00395a68a46939381e78e5545198b-bba8d875fb41e88d-exec-2   1/1     Running             0          3s
4ec00395a68a46939381e78e5545198b-bba8d875fb41e88d-exec-1   1/1     Running             0          5s
4ec00395a68a46939381e78e5545198b-bba8d875fb41e88d-exec-2   0/1     OOMKilled           0          5m
4ec00395a68a46939381e78e5545198b-bba8d875fb41e88d-exec-2   0/1     Terminating         0          5m30s
4ec00395a68a46939381e78e5545198b-bba8d875fb41e88d-exec-2   0/1     Terminating         0          5m30s
4ec00395a68a46939381e78e5545198b-bba8d875fb41e88d-exec-3   0/1     Pending             0          0s
4ec00395a68a46939381e78e5545198b-bba8d875fb41e88d-exec-3   0/1     Pending             0          0s
4ec00395a68a46939381e78e5545198b-bba8d875fb41e88d-exec-3   0/1     ContainerCreating   0          0s
4ec00395a68a46939381e78e5545198b-bba8d875fb41e88d-exec-3   1/1     Running             0          3s
4ec00395a68a46939381e78e5545198b-bba8d875fb41e88d-exec-1   0/1     OOMKilled           0          9m50s
4ec00395a68a46939381e78e5545198b-bba8d875fb41e88d-exec-1   0/1     Terminating         0          10m
4ec00395a68a46939381e78e5545198b-bba8d875fb41e88d-exec-1   0/1     Terminating         0          10m
4ec00395a68a46939381e78e5545198b-bba8d875fb41e88d-exec-4   0/1     Pending             0          0s
4ec00395a68a46939381e78e5545198b-bba8d875fb41e88d-exec-4   0/1     Pending             0          0s
4ec00395a68a46939381e78e5545198b-bba8d875fb41e88d-exec-4   0/1     ContainerCreating   0          0s
4ec00395a68a46939381e78e5545198b-bba8d875fb41e88d-exec-4   1/1     Running             0          4s
4ec00395a68a46939381e78e5545198b-bba8d875fb41e88d-exec-3   0/1     OOMKilled           0          5m13s
4ec00395a68a46939381e78e5545198b-bba8d875fb41e88d-exec-3   0/1     Terminating         0          5m30s
4ec00395a68a46939381e78e5545198b-bba8d875fb41e88d-exec-3   0/1     Terminating         0          5m30s
4ec00395a68a46939381e78e5545198b-bba8d875fb41e88d-exec-5   0/1     Pending             0          0s
4ec00395a68a46939381e78e5545198b-bba8d875fb41e88d-exec-5   0/1     Pending             0          0s
4ec00395a68a46939381e78e5545198b-bba8d875fb41e88d-exec-5   0/1     ContainerCreating   0          0s
4ec00395a68a46939381e78e5545198b-bba8d875fb41e88d-exec-5   1/1     Running             0          4s
4ec00395a68a46939381e78e5545198b-bba8d875fb41e88d-exec-4   0/1     OOMKilled           0          4m37s
4ec00395a68a46939381e78e5545198b-bba8d875fb41e88d-exec-4   0/1     Terminating         0          5m
4ec00395a68a46939381e78e5545198b-bba8d875fb41e88d-exec-4   0/1     Terminating         0          5m
4ec00395a68a46939381e78e5545198b-bba8d875fb41e88d-exec-6   0/1     Pending             0          0s
4ec00395a68a46939381e78e5545198b-bba8d875fb41e88d-exec-6   0/1     Pending             0          0s
4ec00395a68a46939381e78e5545198b-bba8d875fb41e88d-exec-6   0/1     ContainerCreating   0          0s
4ec00395a68a46939381e78e5545198b-bba8d875fb41e88d-exec-6   1/1     Running             0          4s
```

Process will go on till around 30-40 executors are recreated and then the driver restarts and same process unfolds again. I have set the spark application's

```
restartPolicy:
 type:Never
```

Comment: Looking into the docs there are differences between 2.4 and 3.0 releases. Although I am not familiar enough with spark - could you please provide more info about failing kubernetes resources (what is the reason, please use logs and describe failing pods)

Comment: So if this expected to have so many executors you should verify executors configurations - it looks like your resource limits are too high due to `OOMKilled Pods`. Please take a look a this [Kubernetes OOM kill due to limit overcommit](https://sysdig.com/blog/troubleshoot-kubernetes-oom/)